# Problem accessing https - EKS, Fargate, AWS ALB ingress controller, Cert manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am unable to use the certificate issued by cert manager on my eks cluster working with aws alb ingress controller but it worked the moment I switched to aws acm. I have confirmed and the certificate was issued, I am using the right secrets in the cluster issuer and the ingress file